# How to play video in Html

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have problem that play video on website. Firstly I  used below code in localy and these code work . But when I public this page video does not play and give "no video with supported format or  mime type " this error .I use IIS server in Windows. And this page is working under ASP.NET web site.
Here is html code:

```html
<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br> 
<video width="640" height="360"   controls="controls">
    <source src="files/Just.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

    <object width="640" height="375" type="video/quicktime" data="files/Just.mp4"><!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="src" value="files/Just.mp4" />
    
    <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
    <param name="showlogo" value="false" />
    <!--[if gt IE 6]><!-->
    </object><!--<![endif]-->
</video>
</div> 

<script>
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

    function playPause() {
        if (myVideo.paused)
            myVideo.play();
        else
            myVideo.pause();
    }

    function makeBig() {
        myVideo.width = 560;
    }

    function makeSmall() {
        myVideo.width = 320;
    }

    function makeNormal() {
        myVideo.width = 420;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what browser are you using? I assume you are using the same browser in both cases?

Comment: this will help you alot about videos in browser http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html#fbid=EWwJcEzn7-v

Comment: I use firefox but internet explorer and google chrome give me same error

Comment: Read http://caniuse.com/#feat=video as well as its sub-features.

Comment: For what do you need IE conditional tag (gt IE 6)?

Comment: When I use IE tag of course page give me same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no id of video1. Put it after the video tag and then it should work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
    <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
    <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
    <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
    <br>
    <video id="video1" width="420">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
          <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
          <param name="showlogo" value="false" / Your browser does not support HTML5 video. </video>
  </div>

  <script>
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

    function playPause() {
      if (myVideo.paused)
        myVideo.play();
      else
        myVideo.pause();
    }

    function makeBig() {
      myVideo.width = 560;
    }

    function makeSmall() {
      myVideo.width = 320;
    }

    function makeNormal() {
      myVideo.width = 420;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: video id="video1" width="640" height="360"   controls="controls">

Comment: it is true .how can  play mp4 video files in this page. .ogg video is work but .mp4 files is not working

Comment: @mehmet all the mozilla docs state ogg as the preferred video type but to be cross browser compatible you should really offer .ogg, .webm and .mp4 you can convert at video-convert-online.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this on top of your **.htaccess** file:

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v
AddType audio/mp4 m4a
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType audio/ogg ogg oga
AddType video/webm webm
```

[Here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found/) you can read more about it

Comment: I use IIS server .I check it your link but page is about apache server.Any other solution do you know?